# Surjectivity of a recursive sequence over $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $a_{0} = 2$, for $ n \geq 1$ define $a_{n} = \text{min}\{ m \in \mathbb{N} : \text{gcd}(a_{n-1} , m) \neq 1 \hspace{0.3cm} \wedge \hspace{0.3cm} \forall k \leq n-1 \hspace{0.2cm} ( m \neq a_{k})\}  $.

Is it true that each $ m \geq 2$ occurs in this sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as the [EKG sequence](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204011.pdf) (they define $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2$ as starting point instead) and *Lagarias, Rains and Sloane* prove it is a permutation of the integers.